# WPF Docking library

Tags: wpf, windows, controls, docking

I need to use an existing WPF docking library.
There are several libraries:
AvalonDock
.NetBar
SanDock
ActiPro
Infragistics

does anyone has any experiance with one of those libraries?
Can you recommend one of them?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Actipro and it is very good. It's also under active development and improvement

Answer (score 1):

[Sofa](http://sofawpf.codeplex.com) is built on top of AvalonDock and provides interesting features. It can be used with both MEF and Prism and IMHO (as I am a developer of the team) can help a lot for Composite Applications

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/10/08/create-your-own-ide-in-10-minutes.aspx), AvalonDock is being used in [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) 4, so the SharpDevelop guys obviously think it's good!

Comment: But AvalonDock has not been updated since June 2010 and is a bit buggy, so I, for one, am looking for an alternative.